# What is causing my intermittent System.Net.WebException errors?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I have an application that uses's Microsoft Dynamics CRM's API to insert and update records.  Whenever I process a handful of records in a row, I hit the following error when trying to make one of the updates:

```
2013-02-14 10:25:56,382 - Updating lead in dynamics with leadid [3cdaa9d4-c276-e211-99b6-005056ab0822]
2013-02-14 10:25:58,737 - GetProperty
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.Crm.SdkTypeProxy.Metadata.MetadataService.Execute(MetadataServiceRequest Request)
   at Integration.Crm.Services.Dynamics.LeadService.GetPickListvalue(String pickListlable, String logicalAttributeName) in C:\code\DynamicsIntegration\Services\LeadService.cs:line 1256
```

Googling around, I found a few reasons why this particular error (`System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.`) might occurr, but in all cases, it happened **every time** due to misconfiguration or corrupt certificate.

What in the world could possibly trigger this error **intermittently**?

It has nothing to do with the contents of the web request because I can process the same request 5 minutes later and it'll work.  About 10% off all requests to this server result in this error.

**EDIT:** Here's someone with a [similar problem](http://james-brennan.co.uk/2011/10/18/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-send/) using SharePoint, but the error happened every time.

Comment: What version of CRM? How large are the data chunks transferred?

Comment: Is there something in between (Proxies, Firewalls, ...)?

Comment: You're not sharing a context/ IOrganization Service between multiple threads are you?

Comment: Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 (5.0.9690.2243).  There is a firewall between the two, but it's open (which is how it works most of the time).  @Daryl: Nope.

Comment: @Rob Did you ever solve this? I have the exact same issue and no solution for a few weeks now. My connection is also getting closed intermittently at about 10% of the time. In fact, our scenarios are very similer. What hosting service do you use?. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57837975/intermittent-connection-error-on-api-call-until-manual-recycle-of-iis-app-pool)

Answer (score 1):

Use the CRM diagnostic tool to turn on trace logging: http://crmdiagtool2011.codeplex.com to see if you get any additional error information (Assuming you're using On Premise).  I'm guessing there is something not quite right with your SQL Connection from your CRM server to the SQL databases.

Comment: Though the error I'm getting appears to be at the network layer--between the calling server and the CRM REST API--not the database layer.