# Intermittent connection error on API call until manual recycle of IIS app pool

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, hosting, amazon-mws

I am getting reports from amazon reports API using ASP.NET MVC 4.7. I have tested the web app on my local computer and everything works fine. Unfortunately, this is not the case when I publish the site to my HostGator shared server. I continue to get the following error:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
>
> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream

I have found that as soon as I publish the site everything works perfect. After a couple minutes of idling (about 5 minutes) I start to get the error.

**What I have tried:**

1. Turn off firewalls.
2. Contacted HostGator and ensured they are not blocking any IPs
3. I tried adding the following to my startup class as well as right before the request:

   ```
   System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
               | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls
               | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
               | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`
   ```
4. Added `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;` to my startup class. Before adding this I had the error 100% of the time. Now it is working but for a couple min.
5. I have read a dozen stackoverflow questions that have the same error. Most of them recommend adding all the certs as I did above none of which have worked.

I don't know if it is related but when I run this on my host server and look at the log for the connection error. At one point it references my local host *"C:\Users\John\Programs\WebApp-ASPNET\V1.3977p\webapp\Amz_MWS\Web\MarketplaceWebService\MarketplaceWebServiceClient.cs"* See below. Why would it reference my local host address????

```
2019-09-02 19:43:13,652 FATAL[MarketplaceWebService.MarketplaceWebServiceClient]: InnerWebException : System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at MarketplaceWebService.MarketplaceWebServiceClient.Invoke[T,K](IDictionary 2 parameters, K clazz) in C:\Users\John\Programs\WebApp-ASPNET\V1.3977p\webapp\Amz_MWS\Web\MarketplaceWebService\MarketplaceWebServiceClient.cs:line 599
2019-09-02 19:43:13,652 ERROR[MarketplaceWebService.Samples.GetReportRequestListSample]: Caught Exception: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Have you monitor whether the exception was triggered only for specific URL? Besides, have you compared the SSL protocol that was used in working and non working communication? It is suggested to capture net work monitor log to monitor the SSL handshake first.

Comment: @Jokies can you point me towards a tool and/or a tutorial that can describe to me what to look for in the SSL handshake?

Comment: Please try network monitor https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865.  Leave it open in both client and server side. Wait for the problem occur. Monitor which cipher suite, protocol and algorithm are using trying to negotiate. It would probably have something to do with your OS and .NET version